# Possible to merge branches that have been copied in the past but do not share the same root?

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn, svn2git

I have used svn2git to convert a large SVN repository of 10+ thousand commits to a Git repository.

The Git repository works fine but was substantially larger in file size compared to the SVN repo.
The cause for this seems to be that the SVN branches have not been properly created as a new branch, but rather copied the entire file content from the master and worked on top of that.

Therefore, all of the Git branches are [behind the master by 10k+ commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA2eI.png). As the process of manually recreating each branch and running svn2git again would take days, I was wondering whether its possible to merge the root of these related trees to a single source but keep the HEAD separated to continue work on the branches.

Let me know if you need additional information.

[image: []]

Comment: Which `svn2git` tool did you use? There are many of them.

Comment: This one: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

Answer (score 0):

In git you cant merge 2 branch with unrelated history but you can do something else which will work.

## `git cherry-pick`

`git cherry-pick start..end` allow you to pick any commit range from you local repository to any branch regardless to its origin.
This will allow you to "import" any commits form any branch to any other branch in your repo.

Comment: How about `--allow-unrelated-histories` option of `git merge`?